# What should I return from my Async method in C# after doing the insert operation of Azure Table Storage?

Tags: c#, async-await, azure-table-storage

I have an async method named `LogCloudModel`. I am confused about the return type of the method. It has a call to an async method `InsertIntoTableStorage`. Below is the complete code sample.

```
     private static async void LogCloudModel(ModelExecutionContext context)
     {
        var azureStorageAccount = new AzureStorageAccount();
        var cloudModelDetail = new CloudModelDetail();

        //Populate the cloud model
        var cloudModelDetailCollection = PopulateCloudModel(context, cloudModelDetail);

        if (cloudModelDetailCollection == null) return;
        await InsertIntoTableStorage(azureStorageAccount, cloudModelDetailCollection);
        LogTableStorageTransactionResult(azureStorageAccount, operationResult, cloudModelDetail.PartitionKey, cloudModelDetail.RowKey);
      }
```

Currently, I am returning nothing(void). Is my implementation correct?

Comment: `async Task`.  Note, you don't have to actually `return new Task()` or anything.  The task returned is taken care of by the compiler.

Comment: What you return depends on what you need to return. Void is fine if there is no need to notify of the insert's success.

Comment: You may find my article on [async best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) helpful.

Comment: @StephenCleary That's an excellent article by you. I have gone through it a couple of times, but I couldn't make a decision about what to use in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are writing an `event handler` return `Task` instead of `void`, that way callers can `await` on it:

```
private static async Task LogCloudModel(ModelExecutionContext context)
     {
        var azureStorageAccount = new AzureStorageAccount();
        var cloudModelDetail = new CloudModelDetail();

        //Populate the cloud model
        var cloudModelDetailCollection = PopulateCloudModel(context, cloudModelDetail);

        if (cloudModelDetailCollection == null) return;
        await InsertIntoTableStorage(azureStorageAccount, cloudModelDetailCollection);
        LogTableStorageTransactionResult(azureStorageAccount, operationResult, cloudModelDetail.PartitionKey, cloudModelDetail.RowKey);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you return is up to you.  In this case you should atleast return `Task` rather than void, but if you need to return more than (nothing) you can return a `Task<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

**Asynchronous functions** are limited to the following return types:

- `void`
- `Task`
- `Task<TResult>`

The main benefit of returning `Task` instead of `void` is that it allows the caller to attach their own continuations to the returned task, which allow to detect when whether the task failed or not.

I would not return `void` unless you are calling the async method from an event handler.